# Rails associations with search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have issue with associations with search

```
class Manufacturer < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :translations, class_name: 'ManufacturerTranslation', dependent: :destroy

def self.search(query)
    q = query.to_s.parameterize.gsub('-',' ').split
    joins(:translations).where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")
end

and 



 class ManufacturerTranslation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :manufacturer
end
```

so when i have tried to do search and call translations on it

```
Manufacturer.search('fra').last.translations
```

it gives me only translations with name which include `fra`, not all of translations

so i have 6 translations in total for this manufacturer

but after search a get only 2

database schema

```
 create_table "manufacturer_translations" do |t|
    t.integer "manufacturer_id"
    t.string "locale"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "image_source_url"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["manufacturer_id"], name: "index_manufacturer_translations_on_manufacturer_id"
    t.index ["name"], name: "index_manufacturer_translations_on_name"
  end

  create_table "manufacturers", do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "deleted", default: false
  end
```

Comment: in which table you are trying to search name?

Comment: @wasipeer `Manufacturer` example in question

Comment: do you have name field in translations also.

Comment: @wasipeer added schema file

Comment: please accept the answer if it working fine so other can get benefit from this post.

Answer (score 1):

As you are splitting the string you have to loop through all the entities to search them. And you also have to downcase the results. try out the following code:

```
def self.search(query)
    q          = query.to_s.parameterize.gsub('-',' ').split
    conditions = ''
    q.each do |qu|
      conditions = "#{conditions} OR " if conditions.present?
      conditions = "#{condidtions} lower(manufacturers.name) LIKE %#{qu.downcase}%"
    end

    joins(:translations).where(conditions)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you follow Rails conventions I'd suggest you to replace this

`joins(:translations).where("lower(name) LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")`

with

`joins(:translations).where("lower(manufacturers.name) LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")`

May be needed to play with quotations